# Setting up Login in Angular App

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to implement a persistent login for an angular application. By persistent I mean I am able to redirect to a new page or refresh without being logged out. This is kind of a two part question.

1) I am pretty sure my login is working but my logout button gives me a `POST http://localhost:3000/api/sessions 500 (Internal Server Error)`

2) I am now having trouble keeping the username showing in the top right corner of my app after a refresh or after a redirect for third party authentication. (I should also mention I am doing this with the getUser() and get a `GET http://localhost:3000/api/users 401 (Unauthorized)` back

my code is:

html

```
<section class="top-bar-section" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <ul class="right">
      <li>
        <a ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pink">
        <a ui-sref="post-item">Post New Item!</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a ng-click='logout()'>Logout</a>
      </li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href=""><span ng-if="currentUser">{{ currentUser.username }}</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="http://google.com">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

routes.js

```
  app.post('/api/sessions', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    .select('password').select('username')
    .exec( function(err, user){
      if (err) {return next(err)}
      if (!user) {return res.send(401)}
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function (err, valid){
        if (err) {return next(err)}
        if (!valid) {return res.send(401)}
        var token = jwt.encode({username: user.username}, config.secret)
        res.send(token)
      })
    })
  })

  app.get('/api/users', function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.headers['x-auth']){
      return res.send(401)
    }
    var auth = jwt.decode(req.headers['x-auth'], config.secret)
    User.findOne({username: auth.username}, function (err,user){
      if (err) {return next(err)}
        res.json(user)
    })
  })

  app.post('/api/users', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User({username: req.body.username})
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function (err, hash){
      if (err) {return next (err)}
      user.password = hash
      user.save(function (err){
        res.send(201)
      })
    })
  })
```

angular.js

```
 app.service('UserSvc', function($http, $window){
    var svc = this;
    svc.getUser = function() {
      return $http.get('/api/users',{
        headers: { 'X-Auth': this.token }
      })
    }
    svc.login = function(username, password){
      return $http.post('/api/sessions', {
        username: username, password: password
      }).then(function(val){
        svc.token = val.data
        // window.localStorage.token = val.data
        return svc.getUser()
      })
    }

    svc.logout = function() {
      $http.post('/api/sessions', {
        username: null, password: null
      }).then(function(val){
        svc.token = null
        // window.localStorage.token = val.data
      })
    }
  })

  app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location, UserSvc){
    $scope.login = function(username, password) {
      UserSvc.login(username, password)
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.$emit('login', response.data)
        $location.path('/dashboard');
      })
    }
    $scope.logout = function() {
      UserSvc.logout();
      $scope.$emit('logout')
    }
  });

  app.controller('ApplicationCtrl', function($scope, UserSvc) {

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      $scope.currentUser = UserSvc.getUser();
    })

    $scope.modalShown = true;

    $scope.$on('login', function (_, user){
      $scope.currentUser = user;
    })

    $scope.$on('logout', function (){
      $scope.currentUser = null;
    })
  });
```

if anyone has any pointers please let me know! I have spent way to much time on this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make client side persistence I'd save the token in local storage using the [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) service in angular. 
Its a key-value storage.
To store the token in storage use:
`$cookieStore.put('token', data.token)` 
and to retrieve it back use:
`$cookieStore.get('token')`

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

1) When you logout, your `/api/sessions` endpoint is looking for a user with the username of `null` in your database, with something a query of `User.findOne({username: null})`

2) getUser() is setting headers with `'X-Auth'` (note the capitals) but you're checking for lowercase at your users endpoint with `!req.headers['x-auth']`

Answer (score 0):

@XxscurvyxX: You can also use $window.sessionStorage which works on the key/value pair basis and gives getter and setters.

Syntax:

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value) // key: String value: String
$window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) // key: String
```

The key/value pairs stores in the session Storage until you close the tab or close the browser.